# Making tacit assumptions in solve for x problems explicit

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When proving an identity such as
$$\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c} = \frac{a + b}{c}\text{,}$$
the full statement being proven is actually the more pedantic
$$\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c} = \frac{a + b}{c} \text{ if } c \neq 0\text{.}$$

Since I am permitted to assume the condition $c \neq 0$, I can multiply every term by $c$ and prove the identity.

I can also check this more pedantic version at $c = 0$. The condition becomes false, which makes the identity true without having to evaluate division by zero in the consequent.

I'm looking for an analog for solve for $x$ style problems. That is, the pedantic version of solve for $x$ style problems which makes explicit what to do with division by zero. Take the equation
$$\frac{6}{x} = 3$$
who's only solution is understood to be $x=2$.

I can't multiply by $x$ to solve it because I don't know $x \neq 0$. Using the idea,  "when solving for $x$, values which make a denominator zero are not solutions", I can write the problem as the more pedantic system of equations
$$\cases{\frac{6}{x} = 3 \\ x \neq 0\text{.}}$$

Now while working on $\frac{6}{x} = 3$ I can assume $x \neq 0$ and multiply both sides by $x$ to solve.

This version can also be checked at $x = 0$. One of the equations in the system of equations becomes false, which makes the entire statement false without having to evaluate division by zero.

Can I set up problems this way? I'm not suggesting $x \neq 0$ can be added based on some rule of algebra. I'm suggesting it can be added as a way to formally *set up* a solve for $x$ problem in a pedantic style which can then be solved using algebra.

The reason I am asking this is I've seen the concept of tacit conditions for identities in math books, but I've never seen the analogous idea of tacit requirements for solve for $x$ problems. Using it helps me understand what's going on, but I want to make sure it's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about real numbers, the *statement* $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}=\frac{a+b}{c}$ is meaningless for $c=0$. It is not that when you *prove* it you say "if $c\ne0$" but that the statement *per se* includes such condition. If you want to *prove* such identity from the first principle, you need to *define* first what fraction and addition mean.

Exercises in `algebra-precalculus` usually assume functions with [natural domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function#Natural_domain). So equations such as
$$
\frac{6}{x}=3
$$
are implicitly assuming that both sides are meaningful and thus the equation is actually
$$
\frac{6}{x}=3,\quad (x\ne 0). 
$$

To see one more example, it is implicitly assumed in the following equation that $x>2$:

> Solve the equation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-2}}=4$

Comment: I think what I said at the beginning is not clear. Essentially, I'm trying to say mathematicians often leave out writing down the conditions for identities when those conditions are obvious. Writing every condition down makes it clear both how to prove the identity algebraicly and also evaluate the identity at 0. I want to do the same thing for solve for x problems. That said, your discussion of natural domains answers my question. Thank you.